# How to get multiple elements from Json with iterator

Tags: java, json

On the following json, i'd like to get the elements and put every row in a different string, so i made a List.
My problem is that with my snipper i can't get the, for example, Name="name1" and Weight="2" on the same row.

```
string = '{"Name":"name1", "Weight":"3"},{"Name":"name2","Weight":"2"}'
JSONArray jsonarray = (JSONArray) parser.parse(string);
List list = new ArrayList();

Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = jsonarray.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) { 
     list.add(iterator.next().get("Name")+"/"+iterator.next().get("Weight"));
}
```

I need something like ["name1/3","name2/2"]. I know that when i type iterator.next() twice, like i did, i will go on the next element too soon, but i don't know how to do exactly.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Assign the result of the first call to `next()` to an object:

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    JSONObject object = iterator.next();

    list.add(object.get("Name") + "/" + object.get("Weight"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats what i was searching for!